# terminal ls command not showing all files

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ls

I'm familiarizing myself with the terminal, and trying to use the `ls` command is the directory `/usr/bin`.

Unfortunately, it doesn't show me everything in the folder, the terminal cuts it off.

How would I work around this?

[image]

Comment: It only shows from there down, in the case of /usr/bin.

Comment: use `ls -x` to make it show more columns BUT see the scrollbar to the right? if you pull it down it will show more. Besides that: open "profile preferences" see "scrolling" and increase the lines at "scrollback".

Comment: @user313364  you should also try `ls /usr/bin | more` which will limit the display to one page at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run:

```
ls /usr/bin | less
```

Then the output of `ls` will be [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/less.1.html) (a versatile [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager)), which lets you scroll up and down:

- one line at a time, with arrow keys
- one page at a time, with <kbd>B</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>
- in most graphical terminals, with the [mouse wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel)

You can even search the text (below wherever you are in it) by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>, entering your search string, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To quit `less`, press <kbd>q</kbd>. (If that doesn't work, such as when you're in the middle of entering a search string, just press <kbd>Escape</kbd> a couple times first.)

`less` is an extremely handy tool. You can even keep your terminals the default 25 lines tall, if you like, read through multiple pages of output with just the keyboard, fully within the terminal, not having to rely on the features of your terminal emulator application at all.

Besides piping the output of a command to less (`command | less`, as above), you can also use it to view files:

```
less filename
```

`less` is also the default pager used by the [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/man.1.html) command. `man` is another very handy command, because it shows the manpages ("manual pages") for most commands, and some other topics. For example, to read the manual page for the `less` command:

```
man less
```

Answer (score 1):

What has happened here is the buffer Gnome Terminal gives you is limited to a number of lines.

`less` (per Eliah's answer) is almost certainly the best option, especially as it allows you to search the content amongst other things... But you could also increase that buffer. You can make it unlimited if you like but that might mean it uses more RAM than you'd like:

[image]

(Yeah it looks all KDEy, but it really is Gnome Terminal)